# Let $p(x)$ be irreducible polynomial over $F$ then $\{a+\langle p(x)\rangle :\ a\in F\}$ is subfield of $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle $ isomorphic to $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> **Question** Let $F$ be a field & $p(x)$ be irreducible polynomial over $F$.  Show that $\{a+\langle p(x)\rangle\ :\ a\in F\}$ is subfield of $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ isomorphic to $F$

In below attached picture solution to above question is given. But, **I think its wrong!** Because the mapping $\phi$ they considered is not onto. Is am I correct?  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. Take for instance $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $p(x) = x^2-2$. Then, the polynomial $\bar{x} = x+ \langle p(x)\rangle \in \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is not in the image of $\phi$, hence $\phi$ is not onto.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed $\phi$ is not onto. I think they mean "$\phi$ from $F$ to $\{a+\langle p(x)\rangle\mid a\in F\}$". In this case, $\phi$ is indeed onto.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi You're welcome.